I have been getting this error: "jiagu info: vpid 1: terminated with signal 5" trying to write a simple code
I'm new to programing, and I'm trying to write a simple code where I replace every letter in a word with the letter a. Here's my code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

string replaceA (string word) {
    for(int i = word.length() - 1; i < 0; i--) {
        word[i] = 'a';
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << replaceA("hello") << endl;
    return 0;
}

Does anyone know why this is happening?

You have declared replaceA() as returning a string object, but you are not actually return'ing anything. That is undefined behavior.  You are thus passing an invalid string object to operator<<.
Also, your loop is wrong. word.length() is 5, so you are setting i to 4, which is not less-than 0, so the loop exits immediately without doing anything.
Try this instead:
string replaceA (string word) {
    for(int i = word.length()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        word[i] = 'a';
    }
    return word;
}

Or:
string replaceA (string word) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
        word[i] = 'a';
    }
    return word;
}

Alternatively, you can use a range-for loop instead, then you don't have to worry about looping with an index variable:
string replaceA (string word) {
    for(char &ch : word) {
        ch = 'a';
    }
    return word;
}


That being said, there is an even simpler way to write replaceA() without using any loop at all. std::string has a constructor that can repeat a character a specified number of times, eg:
string replaceA (const string &word) {
    return string(word.length(), 'a');
}


If you dont mind me asking, what is std::string and how do I use it and what is size_t and how do i use it? Im sorry I'd these questions sound stupid but I'm a very early beginner.

See std::string and std::size_t. I suggest you get yourself some good C++ books.

 You are using std::string in the initial example. By writing using namespace std;, you are flagging to the compiler to consider class name string to be equivalent to std::string. A statement like using namespace std; is considered bad in header files because not file that includes the header file will want to have all the classes in std namespace in the default namespace. Many people prefer to avoid using namespace std; in CPP files too.
